# ошибка ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема и как её исправить?

Собственно ошибка :

```
    ActionView::MissingTemplate in Chatrooms#show_rooms
Showing /home/denis/prog/as_chat/app/views/chatrooms/show_rooms.html.erb where line #3 raised:

Missing partial chatrooms/_chatroom with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/denis/prog/as_chat/app/views"
  * "/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/devise-a9bb7d031805/app/views"
```

Контроллер

```
  class ChatroomsController < ApplicationController

  def show_rooms
    @chatrooms = Chatroom.all
  end

end
```

Вьюха

```
<h1>Chatrooms</h1>
<div>
  <%= render @chatrooms %>
</div>
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'chatrooms/show_rooms'
  resources :chatrooms

  devise_for :users
  root to: 'rooms#show'

  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас метод `render` во вьюхе ищет шаблон с именем `_chatroom.html.erb`. Он не нужен.

```
<h1>Chatrooms</h1>
<div>
  <%= @chatrooms %>
</div>
```